# Updating multiple records in XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, lambda

### Heading

Hi, I have a lambda running javascript that uses an api to create and update records from one system and into another.

It works but takes a while because the dml statement is in a loop. I really need to iterate over the array and create one instance of the object to update, but am not very familiar with xml.

Based on documentation here is the format I need for multiple records:

```
    <update>
        <technician>
            <id>1355196</id>
            <name>Jim Smith</name>
            <business_unit>Plumbing Service</business_unit>
        </technician>
        <technician>
            <id>1355200</id>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <business_unit>HVAC Sales</business_unit>
        </technician>
    </update>
```

Right now this is format I have, updating one at a time:

```
1st update call: 

    <update>
        <technician>
            <id>1355196</id>
            <name>Jim Smith</name>
            <business_unit>Plumbing Service</business_unit>
        </technician>
    </update>
    

2nd update call: 

    <update>
        <technician>
            <id>1355200</id>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <business_unit>HVAC Sales</business_unit>
        </technician>
    </update>

And so on...
```

Here is the code I have now, one record at a time:

```
    async function updateTechnicians(location, itechs, stechs) {
        
        let logger = bootstrap.logger();
    
        try {
            const client = bootstrap.client(logger);
      
            let sTechMap = new Map();
            
            for(const tech in stechs){
                sTechMap.set(parseInt(stechs[tech].id).toString(), stechs[tech])
            } 
            for(const tech in itechs){
                if(itechs[tech].location == location){
                    
                    let thisTech = sTechMap.get(itechs[tech].servicetitanid)
                    let update = new UpdateTechnician();
                    
                    if(thisTech){
                        
                        update.id = itechs[tech].id;
                        update.name = thisTech.name;
                        update.database_active = thisTech.active;
                    
                        if(thisTech.businessUnit != null){
                            update.tenant = thisTech.businessUnit.tenant.name;
                            update.business_unit = thisTech.businessUnit.name;
                            if(thisTech.businessUnit.name.includes('Phx')){ update.branch = 'Phoenix'; }
                            else if(thisTech.businessUnit.name.includes('Tuc')){ update.branch = 'Tucson'; }
                            else if(thisTech.businessUnit.name.includes('Simi')){ update.branch = 'Simi Valley'; }
                            else if(location == 'NV'){ update.branch = 'Las Vegas'; }
                            else if(location == 'CA'){ update.branch = 'Corona'; }
                        }
                        if(itechs[tech].deactivatedOn != ''){
                            update.deactivatedOn == '';
                        }
                        const response = await client.execute(update);
                        const result = response.getResult();
                    }
                    else{
                        let today = new Date();
                        let date = (today.getMonth()+1)+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear();
                        update.id = itechs[tech].id;
                        update.name = itechs[tech].name;
                        update.database_active = false;
                        if(itechs[tech].deactivatedOn == null){
                            update.deactivatedOn = date;
                        }
                        const response = await client.execute(update);
                        const result = response.getResult();
                    } 
                }
            }
    
        } catch (ex) {
            if (ex instanceof IA.Exceptions.ResponseException) {
                logger.error("A server response exception was thrown", {
                    "Class": ex.constructor.name,
                    "Message": ex.message,
                    "API Errors": ex.errors,
                });
                console.log("Failed! " + ex.message);
            } else {
                logger.error("An exception was thrown", {
                    "Class": ex.constructor.name,
                    "Message": ex.message,
                });
                console.log(ex.name)
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    class AbstractObject extends IA.Functions.AbstractFunction {
        constructor(controlId) {
            super(controlId);
            this.integrationName = 'technician';
        } 
    }
    
    class UpdateTechnician extends AbstractObject {
        constructor(controlId) {
            super(controlId);
        }
        
        writeXml(xml) {
            xml.writeStartElement("function");
            xml.writeAttribute("controlid", this.controlId, true);
            xml.writeStartElement("update");
            xml.writeStartElement(this.integrationName);
    
            xml.writeElement("id", this.id);
            xml.writeElement("name", this.name);
            xml.writeElement("business_unit", this.business_unit);
            xml.writeElement("branch", this.branch);
            xml.writeElement("tenant", this.tenant);
            xml.writeElement("location", this.location);
            xml.writeElement("database_active", this.database_active);
            xml.writeElement("deactivated_on", this.deactivatedOn);
            
            xml.writeEndElement(); // test_object
            xml.writeEndElement(); // create
            xml.writeEndElement(); // function
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from a developer friend. Here is code:

```
async function updateTechnicians(location, itechs, stechs) {
    
    let logger = bootstrap.logger();

    try {
        const client = bootstrap.client(logger);

        let sTechMap = new Map();

        for (const tech in stechs) {
            sTechMap.set(stechs[tech].id.toString(), stechs[tech]);
        }

        let update = new UpdateTechnician();

        for (const tech in itechs) {
            if (itechs[tech].location == location) {

                let thisTech = sTechMap.get(itechs[tech].servicetitanid);
                let updateItem = {};

                if (thisTech) {

                    updateItem.id = itechs[tech].id;
                    updateItem.name = thisTech.name;
                    updateItem.database_active = thisTech.active;

                    if (thisTech.businessUnit != null) {
                        updateItem.tenant = thisTech.businessUnit.tenant.name;
                        updateItem.business_unit = thisTech.businessUnit.name;
                        if (thisTech.businessUnit.name.includes('Phx')) {
                            updateItem.branch = 'Phoenix';
                        } else if (thisTech.businessUnit.name.includes('Tuc')) {
                            updateItem.branch = 'Tucson';
                        } else if (thisTech.businessUnit.name.includes('Simi')) {
                            updateItem.branch = 'Simi Valley';
                        } else if (location == 'NV') {
                            updateItem.branch = 'Las Vegas';
                        } else if (location == 'CA') {
                            updateItem.branch = 'Corona';
                        }
                    }
                    if (itechs[tech].deactivatedOn != null) {
                        updateItem.deactivatedOn == null;
                    }

                    update.arrUpdate.push(updateItem);
                    
                } else {
                    let today = new Date();
                    let date = (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate() + '/' + today.getFullYear();
                    updateItem.id = itechs[tech].id;
                    updateItem.name = itechs[tech].name;
                    updateItem.database_active = false;
                    if (itechs[tech].deactivatedOn == null) {
                        updateItem.deactivatedOn = date;
                    }

                    update.arrUpdate.push(updateItem);
                }
            }
        }

        const response = await client.execute(update);
        const result = response.getResult();
        // console.log(result);

    } catch (ex) {
        if (ex instanceof IA.Exceptions.ResponseException) {
            logger.error("A server response exception was thrown", {
                "Class": ex.constructor.name,
                "Message": ex.message,
                "API Errors": ex.errors,
            });
            console.log("Failed! " + ex.message);
        } else {
            logger.error("An exception was thrown", {
                "Class": ex.constructor.name,
                "Message": ex.message,
            });
            console.log(ex.name);
        }
    }
}

class AbstractObject extends IA.Functions.AbstractFunction {
    constructor(controlId) {
        super(controlId);
        this.integrationName = 'technician';
    }
}

class UpdateTechnician extends AbstractObject {
    constructor(controlId) {
        super(controlId);
        this.arrUpdate = [];
    }

    writeXml(xml) {
        //console.log(this.arrUpdate);
        xml.writeStartElement("function");
        xml.writeAttribute("controlid", this.controlId, true);
        xml.writeStartElement("update");

        for (const i in this.arrUpdate) {
            
            const item = this.arrUpdate[i];
            
            xml.writeStartElement("technician");
            xml.writeElement("id", item.id);
            xml.writeElement("name", item.name);
            xml.writeElement("business_unit", item.business_unit);
            xml.writeElement("branch", item.branch);
            xml.writeElement("tenant", item.tenant);
            xml.writeElement("location", item.location);
            xml.writeElement("database_active", item.database_active);
            xml.writeElement("deactivated_on", item.deactivatedOn);
            xml.writeEndElement();
        }

        xml.writeEndElement(); // create
        xml.writeEndElement(); // function
    }
}
```